# Can I use a Boolean function as a nonlinear constraint with SciPy?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, constraints

I have the following problem:
I'm trying to create a matrix which will map a point `a_i -> b_i`, whilist ensuring that all other points from the space `A` are mapped to points inside the space `B`.
The difficulty is that I'm using a linprog function to check if a point is within a space, and this returns a Boolean, so I'm not sure how to use this as a constraint in optimisation.

Here's my relevant functions, cleaned up:

```
def x_to_matrix(x):
    n = round(np.sqrt(len(x)))
    return np.array(x).reshape((n, n))

def matrix_to_vector(M):
    return M.flatten()

def check_point_within_polytope(point, polytope_points):
    """Uses linprog to check if a point can be decomposed as a convex sum of other points. The `c` vector is null, and `A` gives the basis points together with the requirement that `x` sums to 1"""
    number_of_points = len(polytope_points)
    dim = len(polytope_points[0])
    c = np.zeros(number_of_points)
    A = np.r_[np.array(polytope_points).T, np.ones((1, number_of_points))]
    b = np.r_[point, np.ones(1)]
    lp = linprog(c, A_eq=A, b_eq=b)
    return lp.success


def make_T(local_points, target_points):
    """Challenge here is as follows. We want to create a matrix which maps a particular local point to a particular target point. At the same time, we want to make sure that the matrix maps all other points from the local space into the target space. 
    The difficulty in creating this in enacting these constraints. The way we check that a point is within a space is using linprog, which returns a Boolean rather than numerical result. """
    target_space = target_points + local_points
    target_point = target_points[0]
    local_point = local_points[0]
    
    def function_for_T(x):
        M = x_to_matrix(x)
        new_point = np.dot(M, local_point)
        return np.linalg.norm(target_point - new_point)
    
    def check_local_point_happy(x, local_point):
        M = x_to_matrix(x)
        new_point = np.dot(M, local_point)
        return check_point_within_polytope(new_point, target_space)
    
    nonlinear_constraints = []
    for local_point in local_points:
        fun_here = lambda x: check_local_point_happy(x, local_point)
        nonlinear_constraints += NonlinearConstraint(fun_here, )
    
    X0 = matrix_to_vector(np.eye(len(target_point)))
    
    
    sol = minimize(function_for_T, method='SLSQP', x0=X0, constraints=nonlinear_constraints)
    return sol
```

Is there some way to use my `check_point_within_polytope` function as a nonlinear constraint? Or alternatively is there some much better way of doing this? It feels like there must be since the constraints are, ultimately, linear.
Any help much appreciated!

Comment: I would add this linear constraint directly to the NLP instead of using a separate LP. Good NLP solvers have no problem with linear constraints.  (Scipy has no good constrained NLP solvers: I never, ever use it for anything but toy problems).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen can you recommend an NLP solver for python?

Comment: Also, I wouldn't know how to encode these as linear constraints on an NLP solver. The constraints are that the matrix formed by `x` sends each member of a set of points to a subspace formed by the convex hull of another set of points. I think checking this requires its own optimisation problem, which is what I have with the linprog. Am I missing an easier way of doing this?

Comment: I maybe wrong, but if B is constant and b (the new point) is variable, then we have to enforce that `b[j] = sum(i, w[i]*B[i,j])` with `w` between 0 and 1 and summing up to 1. This can be added as linear constraints to the original NLP.  It is quite possible I am wrong here. I would start with writing down a proper mathematical model. That can help in reasoning about this. Your idea to call an LP solver from inside, does not look like a feasible approach to me (one would need a proper decomposition scheme).